# asynchronous web-component in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-component

I have a sidebar component that should changes its content when the user is authenticated. The trouble is the script run before the authentication is getted. The way I tried is making a observedAttributes() method that listen when the attributed auth is made, but that doesn't work

```
class sidebarComponent extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
       
   }

   static get observedAttributes() {
       return ['authenticated']
   }

   attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
       if(attr === 'authenticated') {
           this.authenticated = newVal;
       }
   }

   getTemplate() {
       const template = document.createElement('template');
       console.log(this.authenticated)
       if(this.authenticated == 'true') {
           template.innerHTML = `
           <div class="component">
               <ul class="list">
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">Mi Cuenta</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">Desconectarse</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           ${this.getStyle()}
           `
       } else {
           template.innerHTML = `
           <div class="component">
               <ul class="list">
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">Registrarse</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">Iniciar Sesion</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           ${this.getStyle()}
           `
       }
       
       return template;
   }
   
   getStyle() {
       return `
           <style>
               /*styles*/
           </style>
       `
   }

   render() {
       this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.getTemplate().content.cloneNode(true))
   }

   connectedCallback() {
       this.render()
   }
}

customElements.define('sidebar-component', sidebarComponent)
```

also I tried with async/await but I didn't find the way to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `authenticated` property is not linked to any global property or event. So the component has to actively be notified of any changes to the auth state of your site/app.

In detail: the component only handles changes of html attributes like
`<sidebar-component authenticated="true"></sidebar-component>`

There are not getter / setter for the property so something like

`document.querySelector('sidebar-component').authenticated = "true"`

won't work.

Second the component is only rendered once at `connectedCallback`. Any changes of the `authenticated` property should trigger a re-render - so possibly add `this.render()` to your `attributeChangedCallback` function, and make sure new content is not appended but replaces old content.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply. The way I got it for now is adding a cookie that shows if the user is authorized (auth=true). The component can read it inside without attributes. This may not be the best practice, but helps me to charge the component inmediatly (the component don't show sensitive information).

I didn't think in getters/setters to solve the problem,I will try to apply it. Thanks again!